# Why is the selected value not displayed in the "lightning-combobox"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox, lightningselect

**//html**

```
            <lightning-combobox
                name="selectedYear"
                value={currentYear}
                placeholder="Select Year"
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChangeYear}>
            </lightning-combobox>
```

**//js**

```
@track currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
@track options;

    handleChangeYear(event) {
        this.currentYear = event.detail.value;
    }

    getYears(){
        getYears()
            .then((returnedData) => {
                let years = [];
                returnedData.forEach((item) => {
                    years.push( {label : 'Regional Expenses ' + item.Year, value : item.Year })
                });
                years.sort((a, b) => a.value > b.value ? -1 : 1);
                this.options = years;
                this.currentYear = years[0].value;
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

**//options:**

```
[{"label":"Regional Expenses 2021","value":2021},{"label":"Regional Expenses 2020","value":2020},{"label":"Regional Expenses 2019","value":2019},{"label":"Regional Expenses 2018","value":2018}]
```

After loading the page, I get the default value selected:

[image]

But after selecting any other value , it is not saved and I only see the placeholder label...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of your options is a number, while `event.detail.value` holds a string, so after selecting an option `this.currentYear` will hold a wrong value, i.e. `'2020'` instead of `2020`.

The [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) is the fastest way to convert it to a number:

```
handleChangeYear(event) {
    this.currentYear = +event.detail.value;
}
```